# Excel 2010 - Conditional Formatting Multiple Cells

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I'm using Excel 2010 on Windows 7

I have a drop down in column A (options to select are open and closed) and when I select the option of closed then i would like ONLY specific cells within that row to be 'greyed out'.

Unfortunately I only know a formula to format a whole row `(=INDIRECT("A"&ROW())="Closed")` but this does not work for me as i only require specific cells to be greyed out and not the whole row

Please advise of the correct formula which i can apply to the whole spreadsheet.

Cell which contains the drop down options of open, closed: A6
Corresponding cells within that row which require formatting: `B6 D6 E6 G6 I6 J6 K6 M6 N6`

Answer (score 1):

Apply the conditional formatting to the first cell then in the conditional formatting rules manager,input in the applies to box `=B6,D6,E6,G6,I6,J6,K6,M6,N6`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Are you able to provide the specific formula that I would need to apply to the first cell?

Comment: @Damian what do these `B...N6` cells contain? `Open` or `Closed` values or smth else?

Comment: `=IF(A6="Closed",1,0)` then apply the format you want. Then you want to apply it to the cells listed above

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells you want the conditional formatting to apply to with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and the mouse. Then goto *Home* tab->*Styles*->*Conditional Formatting*->*Manage rules*->New rule_->*Use formula to determine which cells to forma* and apply this formula `=$A1="Closed"`.

That will apply the format to all in the selection. The `$A1` will ensure all cells in row 1 check column A.

In case you want to apply the format to some other cells later, you can simply adjust this in the Rules Manager.